# Is there any guide for setting MongoDB as analysis DB of WSO2 BAM instead of Cassandra?

Tags: wso2

According the IT policy of our company, the Cassandra is not allowed to use since of some reason, I need to replace with MongoDB as the analysis DB of WSO2 Business Activity Monitor.   Is there any documents for setting MongoDB on WSO2 BAM 2.4.1? many appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in the current version of BAM (2.4.1) MongoDB can not be used as a replacement to Cassandra.

MongoDB support is in the WSO2 BAM road-map and it will be available in the future.

Is there any particular reaseon why you would want to replace Cassandra with MongoDB in your implementation?